# Best name for the weather / climate tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We already have a [weather](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather) tag, and it already has [climate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) as a synonym.

It makes sense for them to be synonyms because the questions often don't clearly differentiate, which is fine.

But it can look a little odd when a question is clearly talking only about climate but the tag says just "weather".

I think we would be better off including both terms in the tag. Let's have a little vote for which way to do it would be best... just because we can (-:

Comment: Hah, I was thinking about this very subject when I made the latest weather question ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option:

- [weather-and-climate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-and-climate)

Comment: Looks like we have a winner. @markmayo would you like to perform the delicate operation?

Comment: Failing that, how about you @ankurbanerjee ? (-:

Answer (score 1):

Option:

- [climate-and-weather](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-and-weather)

Answer (score -4):

Option:

- [climate-weather](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-weather)

Answer (score -4):

Option:

- [weather-climate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-climate)